# Subscribe SNS by SQS sam yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, sam

Here is sam yaml snippet:

```
  SnsTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: !Sub ${Env}-sns-topic
      TopicName: !Sub ${Env}-sns-topic

  Queue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Sub ${Env}-queue
      VisibilityTimeout: 300
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
      ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 20
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt Dlq.Arn
        maxReceiveCount: 5

  Dlq:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Sub ${Env}-dlq
      VisibilityTimeout: 300
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
      ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 0

  TestSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    DependsOn: 
      - SnsTopic
      - Queue
      - Dlq
    Properties:
      Protocol: sqs
      TopicArn: !Ref SnsTopic
      Endpoint: !GetAtt 
        - Queue
        - Arn
      RawMessageDelivery: true
```

I am trying to create an SNS that is subscribed to an SQS with a Dead Letter Queue (DLQ). After deployment, I can see that the SNS and SQS have been created successfully, but the SQS subscription to the SNS does not appear to be working. When I check the subscriptions for the SQS, I can see that the SNS that was created in the same stack is listed, but I have to manually add the subscription for it to work. I'm wondering what could be causing this issue or if there's something missing in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup [AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-policy.html#aws-properties-sqs-policy-syntax) to allow SNS to send messages to the queue. Check [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.cloudformation.html) for examples of how to do it.